# Format ip address range

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipv6, ipv4

I did not know how to start on this, so i would appreciate a point in the right direction. say i have a an iprange in ipv4 or ipv6.

```
   1.0.32.0 - 1.0.63.255
   2620:0:860:: - 2620:0:860:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

I want to format that to

```
   a.b.c.d/ee
   a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i/jj
```

via c#. I don't how to start on it. is there any c# classes that i could to to covert such ranges to the given format. any pointers on how to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470792 (it's the other way around, but it might help get you started)

Comment: Thank you very much that solves the issue of converting the ipv4.. :) thanks for pointing me to that post :) :) i think i got it :)

Comment: @Heinzi: Give that as an answer so that OP can accept for other users who reach here can be guided looking for same.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: I feel that it is not complete enough for an answer (it does not cover the IPv6 case and it's only a helpful pointer for the IPv4 case), but maybe I'll do it if nobody provides a better answer in reasonable time.

Comment: Yes. its only for ipv4.. which is 50% of what i need.. i am grateful for his help but it would do wonders if I could get how to do the ipv6 address range to CIDR notation as well :)

Comment: @Heinzi:do you have an idea on the ipv6 issue.i still didnt find any solution. thank you very much :)