# Extract Delimited values and create columns with T-SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following table called `DQS_Raw` with two columns.

**DQS_Raw**

```
id    Result
-----------------    
1   |01|00|00|01
2   |00|01|01|00
3   |00|00|00|01
```

I need to use a stored procedure to get the below table result.

The below table has 6 columns.

**DQS_Raw**

```
id  Result        VF02a VF02b VF02c VF05b
------------------------------------------    
1   |01|00|00|01  01    00    00    01
2   |00|01|01|00  00    01    01    00
3   |00|00|00|01  00    00    00    01
```

As noted here the values between the pipe delimited characters are extracted. The first extracted values are assigned to the column VF02a, the second assigned to VF02b and so on.

I also need this to be dynamic enough in case the order changes from the input.

Please don't use a set based approach.

Jono

Comment: Stop storing delimited values in a single column.

Comment: Apologies, set base approach...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess that's what he's doing by splitting it up? :)

Comment: I wish I could but business has decided otherwise...My process only starts from picking it up with delimited values...

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: well not really: he is trying to retrieve the comma separated values in a "dynamic" manner. Doesn't sound like he actually wants to fix the data model.

Comment: SQL is all about using "Set based approaches". If you don't want to, perhaps you should use a different language.

Comment: Similar Question is [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968607/calculating-the-number-of-hosts-in-a-netmask-using-tsql/17969556#17969556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be impossible to make this a dynamic approach.

But you can do something like this to split the value

I assume your using `ssms 2010` server

```
select *,  
SUBSTRING(Result,2,2) as VF021,  
SUBSTRING(Result,5,2) as VF02b,  
SUBSTRING(Result,8,2) as VF02c,  
SUBSTRING(Result,11,2) as VF05b  
from DQS_RAW
```

Comment: @JonathanCubitt Tnx! :)